# Laravel whereDoesntHave union whereHas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to query my models that don't have relation and union it with the ones that have relations but I get an error with memory being exhausted.

```
Post::whereDoesntHave('comments')
    ->union(Post::newQuery()->whereHas('comments')->getQuery())
    ->paginate();`
```

Anyone know a better way of using the union?

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Post Model with below code.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class); //Pass Foreign Key if other than id
    }
}
```

Update Your Comment Model with this code.

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);//Pass Foreign Key if other than id
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);//Pass Foreign Key if other than id
    }
    public function scopeNoComment($query)
    {
        return $query->count() == 0;
    }

}
```

```
$comments = $post->NoComment()->with('user')->paginate(10);
```

Making a relationship would be easy to access data.

Comment: The goal is list of the post that have no comments first and last are the posts with comments ergo the union.